# Modal with WKWebView closes when focusing on an text input, textarea, number input

Tags: html, macos, macos-sierra, wkwebview

I have this issue with a WKWebView placed inside an modal:

I open and modal and place a WKWebView inside. I load an url and everything works fine until I try to click (focus) on a input field and then it just crashes and closes the modal. Interesting thing is that it works on my MAC, but on another one it doesn't. Both are using MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

I also tried with a blank html page with only an input placed inside of it and it crashed again.

This is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Webkit/WebKit.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#define MSGSZ     128


using namespace std;

typedef struct msgbuf {
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MSGSZ];
} message_buf;


@interface Window_delegate : NSObject <NSWindowDelegate>
@end



@interface App_delegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSWindow *_window;
@end

@implementation App_delegate

-(instancetype)init:(NSWindow*)parent_window
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self._window = parent_window;
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}


-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)a_notification
{

    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration =
    [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];

    //    theConfiguration.suppressesIncrementalRendering=YES;

    WKWebView *wb = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self._window.contentView.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
    wb.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://p416884.mittwaldserver.info/site/public"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [wb loadRequest:request];
    wb.frame = CGRectMake(self._window.contentView.frame.origin.x,self._window.contentView.frame.origin.y, self._window.contentView.frame.size.width, self._window.contentView.frame.size.height);

    [self._window.contentView addSubview:wb];
}
@end


void start_program(void)
{
    NSApplication *app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    // Critical to have this so that you can add menus
    [NSApp setActivationPolicy:NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];


    NSWindow *window =
    [[NSWindow alloc]
     initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1200, 900) styleMask: NSWindowStyleMaskClosable backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: YES];

    [window center];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:window];
    [window setStyleMask:[window styleMask] | NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable];
    [window setTitle:@"Saint-Gobain Baustoffwelt"];


    App_delegate *application_delegate = [[App_delegate alloc] init:window];
    app.delegate = application_delegate;
    [app activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    [app run];
}




int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //    std::cout << "Starting Application\n";


    @autoreleasepool {
        start_program();
    }

    return 0;

}
```

And this is what I get in the Console.app when it crashes: [link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXPkS.jpg)

I will be very grateful if you can somehow help me out..

Comment: A little update:

I get this error when I debug in xcode:

error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) on the line with [app run]


This bug seems to happen on two new 2017 Macbook pro's and everythings works fine on two older IMacs ...

Comment: One other thing I noticed is that if the input is password it doesn't crash at all ...